# "this" returning a function instead of object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, foreach, this

In the below javascript code I wanted to know which object does "this" point to.But instead I am getting a function.

I thought "this" always referred to the object calling that function.
So can anyone explain why this behaviour ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var Paper = function() {};

  Paper.prototype = {
    populate: function(data) {
      data.questions.forEach(function(entry) {
        //printing a function instead of object
        console.log(this);
      }.bind(this));
    }
  };


  var paperDataLoader = function() {
    this.callbacks = [];
  };

  paperDataLoader.prototype = {

    //accepts a callback to notify the registered function
    registerDataLoaded: function(callback) {
      this.callbacks.push(callback);
    },

    //calls the callback functions when data is loaded
    loadData: function() {
      $.ajax('../find_paper.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        contentType: 'text'
      }).done(function(ajaxData) {
        this.paperData = $.parseJSON(ajaxData);
        for (var i = 0; i < this.callbacks.length; i++)
          this.callbacks[i](this.paperData);
      }.bind(this));
    }
  };


  var loader = new paperDataLoader();
  var paper = new Paper();
  loader.registerDataLoaded(paper.populate);
  loader.loadData();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The value of `this` changes depending on it's context. Which line are you having trouble with?

Comment: line with console.log

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me:

```
var Paper = function() {};

Paper.prototype = {
    populate: function(data) {
        data.questions.forEach(function(entry) {
            console.log(this);
        }.bind(this));
    }
};

var paper = new Paper();
paper.populate({ questions: [ 1 ] }); // prints paper object
```

Maybe you're re-binding `paper.populate` somewhere?

Comment: I am storing paper.populate in a paperDataLoader.callbacks array which is then called inside .done() method when ajax request is successfull

Comment: try calling paper.populate like I have